# howto get name of MEDIASUBTYPE from AM_MEDIA_TYPE, c++

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow, fourcc

I am using directshow to grab frames fro my webcam. During the configuration of the webcam (when I set the resolution, fps and so) I have multiple alternatives available from the cam. (47 of them).

Currently i use a for loop which iterates through all available settings of the cam, and I just print the values in the console. But I have no good way to print the value of the Media sub type.

Is there a good method to print the actual name of the media subtype?

Now I test it like this:

```
if(mT->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_MJPG){
     printf(" MEDIASUBTYPE_MJPG ");
} else {
     printf(" ----- ");
}
```

(mT = AM_MEDIA_TYPE)
Which is not a good way. I would like to use something that prints the actual name of the subtype.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Media subtype is just a `GUID` identifier, nameless. There is no way to convert it to user friendly string without direct comparison to the values you are aware of.

There is only one exception here and it is the identifiers mapped from Four Character Codes (FourCCs). See details on these on MSDN in [`FOURCCMap` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you might want to do something like:

```
if(memcmp(&mT->subtype.Data2, &MEDIASUBTYPE_MJPG.Data2, sizeof (GUID) - offsetof(GUID, Data2)) == 0)
{
  // NOTE: This is FourCC!
  CHAR pszValue[5];
  *((UINT32*) pszValue) = mT->subtype.Data1;
  pszValue[4] = 0;
  _tprintf(_T("Media Subtype is FourCC %hs\n"), pszValue);
} else
// ...
```